# Help with this ADB REVERSE Tethering Script?

Tags: adb, reverse-tether, scripts

I added the functionality to automatically turn on reverse tethering after many fails:

Now i only enter `t` into terminal

```
alias t='r && sz $tether && r && sz $n'
tether='am start -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.TetherSettings && input keyevent 66 && input keyevent 66'
n='netcfg rndis0 dhcp'
alias sz='ad shell'
alias de='ad devices -l'
alias r='ad kill-server && ad start-server'
alias ad='adb'
alias pu='adb push'
```

**The issues with the above are:** (2 is most important)

1. This only works with the screen on and when notification bar isn't pulled down
2. This doesn't simulate wi-fi/other wirelessnetworking or make apps actually try to connect to net instead of checking if wifi/other wirelessnetworking is enabled
3. This code can most probably be much shorter/optimized (but at least it works)

> To understand the background better please see my original question:[I can reverse tether now by using alias but it stops on adb shell command](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65646/i-can-reverse-tether-now-by-using-alias-but-it-stops-on-adb-shell-command)